# When down-sizing my website, one of my a tags starts to get hidden and a horizontal scroll bar appears

Tags: html, css

This is my first website and i'm doing it for a project at school nut i've got a couple of problems. First, when resizing my website one of my buttons starts to disappear for some reason. Secondly, my background color disappears when going below 992px of width. This project is due this week and this is the last part. Anyways, here is my code, the classes, ids and text are in french but the actual code is in english.The image that doesn't appear is supposed to be 2000px by 391px

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
:root {
  --ming: #16697A;
  --pacific-blue: #489FB5;
  --middle-blue: #82C0CC;
  --isabelline: #EDE7E3;
  --orange-peel: #FFA62B;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --black: #000000;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 400 100%/150% Montserrat, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 150%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#entete,
#pied-page {
  background: var(--pacific-blue);
  color: var(--white);
}

#entete {
  padding: 5%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #entete {
    padding: 5% 5% 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  #entete {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .wrapper-navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #logo,
  #menu {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  #logo {
    padding: 3% 0% 3% 5%;
  }
}

#pied-page * {
  color: white;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 0.063rem solid #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

#menu ul li a span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

#menu ul li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #menu ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  #menu ul li {
    padding-top: .5rem;
  }
  #menu ul li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    line-height: 1.125rem;
  }
  #menu ul li a span {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu ul li.active {
    background: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  }
  #menu ul li.active a {
    color: var(--pacific-blue);
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="entete">
  <div class="wrapper-navigation">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images-meme/La culture des memes-logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page-autonomie.html">Introduction <span>au site</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="Swole Doge vs Cheems.html"><span>Doge</span> Cheems</a></li>
        <li><a href="Spiderman.html">Spiderman <span>meme</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="HeHeHeHa!.html"><span>Clash</span> Royale</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="Informations.html">Informations <span>importantes</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries need to have larger values.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
:root {
  --ming: #16697A;
  --pacific-blue: #489FB5;
  --middle-blue: #82C0CC;
  --isabelline: #EDE7E3;
  --orange-peel: #FFA62B;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --black: #000000;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 400 100%/150% Montserrat, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

@media screen and (min-width:1328px) {
  html {
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 150%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#entete,
#pied-page {
  background: var(--pacific-blue);
  color: var(--white);
}

#entete {
  padding: 5%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #entete {
    padding: 5% 5% 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1328px) {
  #entete {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1328px) {
  .wrapper-navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #logo,
  #menu {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  #logo {
    padding: 3% 0% 3% 5%;
  }
}

#pied-page * {
  color: white;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 0.063rem solid #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

#menu ul li a span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

#menu ul li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #menu ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  #menu ul li {
    padding-top: .5rem;
  }
  #menu ul li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    line-height: 1.125rem;
  }
  #menu ul li a span {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu ul li.active {
    background: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  }
  #menu ul li.active a {
    color: var(--pacific-blue);
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="entete">
  <div class="wrapper-navigation">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images-meme/La culture des memes-logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page-autonomie.html">Introduction <span>au site</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="Swole Doge vs Cheems.html"><span>Doge</span> Cheems</a></li>
        <li><a href="Spiderman.html">Spiderman <span>meme</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="HeHeHeHa!.html"><span>Clash</span> Royale</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="Informations.html">Informations <span>importantes</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```